# Need to load latest version of specific assembly

Tags: vb.net, reflection, assemblies, gac

I have this situation where LoadWithPartialName appears to be the only good alternative, although it is marked as Obsolete.

First, keep in mind that I work in a very tight dev environnement with versionning and deployement policies that cannot be easily changed or bypassed.

Let's say there's a .NET executable that I have no control on (from another division). Let's call this the client AppA application. AppA's version is 10.11.12.x.

Application AppA has a direct reference to one of our class library that provides some service to the caller (returns some information). Let's call it SvcB and the version is also 10.11.12.x.

Now, AppA's division does not need to update their system as often as we do, so AppA's version will stay 10.11.12.x for some time, probably until we decide to change the format of the class that is exchanged between us.

Our division needs to change the logic behind the service SvcB more often and the version must change with every major deployement. So let's say we change the logic and we deploy a new version of SvcB, 11.02.11.x. AppA will still reference the old version, so the logic being used is now incorrect.

We are thinking of creating a new "facade" to our service. Let's call it SvcFrontB. SvcFrontB's version will stay the same, in sync with the AppA's own version.

Now I need SvcFrontB to load the most recent version of SvcB through reflection. This way, I am sure the latest logic is always used.

How do I achieve that without using LoadWithPartialName ?

Thanks
Guy

Comment: I'm not sure because i've never done such a thing, but maybe an alternative is in this SO-Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557010/how-to-determine-the-latest-version-number-of-a-gac-assembly
"Using a managed wrapper around the Fusion API (fusion.dll) you could enumerate the assemblies in the GAC, filter them by name and order by version."

Comment: I've seen the Fusion DLL, yes. However, the DLL is not in the GAC and I don't see how I could load it on the server.

Comment: This quacks like an organizational problem.  Very hard to solve them with software, especially when the only way left is LoadWithPartialName.  The pragmatic solution is so simple, copy them all into one directory.  Everybody still knows what file belongs to them and the CLR cannot get it wrong.  If anybody objects "you can't do that!", ask the simple question.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

From samples I've downloaded, I now realize that Fusion.dll is an API that you don't really need to reference. I've downloaded the sample GacTool (MSjogren.Fusion.Native) and see no reference at all in the project.

However, the code in there seems a little complex. Is there a simple way to get a list of all versions of an assembly in the GAC ?

For example, if I could get a list of all SvcB in the GAC, the list would contain two assemblies, version 10.11.12.x and version 11.02.11.x. Then I would be able to decide which one is the latest and use the Assembly.Load command to load it.

Or perhaps there is even a more direct way to retrieve the latest version of an assembly using the Fusion API ?

Any help appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out how.

Since the DLL SvcFrontB from from where I will be calling SvcB will also be in the GAC, I can easily find it's location, therefore the GAC location too.

From there, I user Directory.GetFiles to get all the versions of SvcB currently in the GAC and analyse them using Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo to find out the latest version.

Since I already know the name and PublicKeyToken and now have the full version, I can do an Assembly.Load.

Going a little further, for testing purposes (in dev envirronment only), I will also be looking for a key in the App.Config pointing me to the exact DLL path to use. By comparing this to the one found in the GAC, I will be able to really use the latest version.

Thanks